# Python exception handling in less lines

Tags: python, exception, error-handling

I am having a lot of exception statement in my code block and I need to shorten the code to 100 lines. Is there a better way with less lines to write one of my exception codes below?

```
while True: 
    try:
        difficulty = int(input("Choose level 1: Easy  2: Difficult): "))
        if (difficulty!=1 and difficulty!=2):
            raise ValueError # this will send it to the print message
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter the right value")
```

Comment: Why 100 lines? How many lines do you have now? How many of the lots of 8 lines above do you have now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Less lines of code is not always better!***

However, there are some things you can improve here. For example, for the limited amount of valid input values in your example, the error handling is overly complicated: you check for exceptions due to the input not being a number, but you also check if the number is one of the two allowed numbers.  Instead, you could also just check if the input is one of the two valid *strings*. If it is, you know for sure the conversion to int can be done without exceptions, so you don't need the try-catch block.

The smallest code I can come up with is 5 lines of code for the same functionality:

```py
response = None
while response not in ['1', '2']:
    response = input("Choose level 1: Easy  2: Difficult): ")
    if response not in ['1', '2']: print("Please enter the right value")
difficulty = int(response)
```

However, optimization might be more effective on the global scope (i.e. if you look a bit further then only this piece of code). For example, depending on what you want to do with the variable `difficulty`, the conversion to `int` might not be necessary at all. In that case you could remove the last line as well.

But like I said before, less lines does not necessarily make the code better. For maintainability, [readability counts](https://peps.python.org/pep-0020/#the-zen-of-python).

Answer (score 0):

> [...] with less lines to write one of my exception codes below?

Not exactly... but you can shorten it by one line if you want:

```
while (difficulty!=1 and difficulty!=2):
```

This will make useless the `raise` and the `if` statement.